# Apache poi library not added

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I haven't been working much with jars so I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I've tried following guides. In library I have tried adding the jar as Classes, Jar Directory, native library location and sources and it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Screenshot of Jetbrains IntelliJ where you can see problem in import.]
[image: Screenshot of Jetbrains IntelliJ Project Structure -> Librairies screen: 3 librairies imported (poi-3.5-FINAL & poi-3.5-FINAL1 & poi-3.5-FINAL2)]

Comment: Did you checked [Correct way to add external jars (lib/*.jar) to an IntelliJ IDEA project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Yes, I have done so. I've added them to the modules as well as library. For me they don't show up under external libraries folder though but in the root folder, not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: Is this a Maven based project?